# console.log() doesn't work in Firefox but in IE

Tags: javascript, firefox, console.log

I am coding some Javascript and want to debug my code, but I don't get something into the console. console.log() simply doesn't work in Firefox 67.0.4.

I don't use Firebug and all Tabs (Errors, Warnings, Log, Information, Debug) in the Console are activated.

I just tried it in IE and it works. There are a few similar topics here on stackoverflow, but the solutions didn't help me.

Has anyone a clue how to fix this problem?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/cCKxpaP  Make sure you have the logging options enabled (in my picutre the highlighted ones are the ones "enabled")

Answer (score 0):

there is a few things you can check:

- clear the "filter" field above the console
- check that all the log level are checked (Errors, Warnings, Log, Information, Debug buttons above console)
- are you sure that the code where the `console.log()` is actually executed?
- keep in mind that if the page is reloaded the console will be emptied unless "keep log" is checked

Comment: Thanks! I didn't check "keep log", this is the problem. Now it works :)